# Does re-using a React component reduce Webpack bundle size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Apologies if this is a duplicate! Couldn't find an answer.

My question is this: If I have a React component that is used in multiple places, will Webpack copy the code into each location when bundling, or just pass a reference to it? I'm trying to understand if making re-usable components will reduce bundle size or not.

I'm thinking that for built-in React components like `<p>`, `<li/>`, these are just referenced, so that having 2 `<p/>` elements is not twice as expensive as having one. I'm guessing/hoping(?) that the same is true for higher-level components that contain multiple elements.

Not familiar at all with Webpack. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using e.g. `MyComponent` in both your `Home` and `Login` components will not include the `MyComponent` code twice, it will only be included once in the final bundle.

Comment: Found a twitter post that goes into some more detail regarding this. https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/841258118810075138?lang=en

Comment: Fab! Thanks so much!